# cropper.js could not be initialized not showing any error

Tags: javascript, image, cropperjs, cropper

Hi guys i am stuck with javascript library cropper.js. I want to initialize cropper when image is uploaded. I made a function named temp, that trigger when input type file is changed have a look at code
html

```html
<input
  type="file"
  name="cropableImage"
  id="cropableImageId"
  onchange="temp(this)" 
/>
```

javascript

```js
function temp(input) {
  if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#previewHolder').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    $("#main_image_section").show();
    $("#choose_file").hide();
    $("#tools_section").show();
    const image=document.getElementById('previewHolder');
    cropper = new Cropper(image, { 
      zoomable: true,
      scalable:true,
      rotatable:true,
      autoCropArea:0.5,
      background:false,
      modal:true,
      autoCrop: true, 
      viewMode: 0,
      cropBoxResizable:true,
      setDragMode:true,
    });
  } else {
    alert('select a file to see preview');
    $('#previewHolder').attr('src', '');
  }
}
```

function is running and image loads when i select image. No error shows in console. but the cropper do not initialized.

it works when i perform this action in another way. Like i made a button and when clicks the button, function runs and cropper is initialized.

but i need it initialized when image is loaded.

Comment: You are trying to initialize it, _before_ the image has even loaded. This needs to go into the `reader.onload` callback.

Answer (score 2):

The `reader` has to take time before it has read the file you've uploaded. That means that `new Cropper` is called **before** the `reader.onload` function has run.

If you want cropper to run **after** the file is read, then move initialization of `Cropper` inside the `onload` callback, after you assign the `src` of the preview holder image.

```
let cropper;
const previewHolder = document.getElementById("previewHolder");

function temp(input) {
  if (input.files.length) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      // Here the image is loaded. 
      // Set it to the preview holder.
      previewHolder.src = e.target.result;

      // Now the cropper should be able to use the loaded image.
      cropper = new Cropper(previewHolder, {
        zoomable: true,
        scalable: true,
        rotatable: true,
        autoCropArea: 0.5,
        background: false,
        modal: true,
        autoCrop: true,
        viewMode: 0,
        cropBoxResizable: true,
        setDragMode: true,
      });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```